# How to use the replace() method with keyword arguments to replace empty strings

Tags: python, pandas

I tried to use **pandas.DataFrame.replace()** to fill empty strings in a frame via the code below.

main_datasets = [train_data, test_data, alt_data1, alt_data2]

```
for data in main_datasets:
    for x in data:
        if type(x) == 'int':
            x.fillna(x.median(), inplace = True)
        elif type(x) == 'float':
            x.fillna(x.median(), inplace = True)
        else:
            x.replace(to_replace = None, value = 'N/A', inplace = True)
```

However, I continue to receive the following exception, despite using characters or numbers for the keyword value and removing the keyword name:

```
TypeError: replace() takes no keyword arguments
```

Why is this error raised from "***value = 'N/A?'***"

Here is an ad hoc sample of some fields (separated by commas):

> 12123423,       0,           M,              Y,           120432.5
>
> 12654423,       1,           F,              N,           80432.5
>
> 12123423,       0,           M,              Y,           120432.5
>
> 12123423,       0,           M,              Y,           120432.5

Comment: Can you post a small sample of your dataframe with a desired output?  See: [mcve]

Comment: The error message you're receiving is because you're passing keyword arguments to the `replace()` method--what a surprise! /s 

You need to pass positional arguments. Try `replace(None, 'N/A', True)` :)

Answer (score 3):

You are trying to use the `pandas.DataFrame.replace()` method but you are actually using the `string.replace` method.

I'd suspect that all of this would fail but you are hitting the failure on the not `int` and not `float` case first. If x is an int, than it is not a DataFrame and wouldn't have the `.fillna` method. Similarly, strings have Python's replace method but that has a different function signature.

[df.replace()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.22/generated/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html) vs  [string.replace()](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_replace.htm)

`str.replace(old, new[, max])`

vs

`DataFrame.replace(to_replace=None, value=None, inplace=False, limit=None, regex=False, method='pad', axis=None)`

I also suspect you are trying to use [Series.dtype](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dtype.html#pandas.Series.dtype) rather than type.

Comment: Yes, I tried to use dtype but I kept receiving an error using the fields in the dataframe. If I'm understanding correctly, there is another replace() method in the namespace.

Comment: More similar to different methods on different classes. When you use dot notation, that's accessing a different namespace.

Comment: It makes sense. I figured the different methods were in completely different modules. However, I'm still don't understand why x as an int wouldn't be a DataFrame able to access the .fillna() method. Are you saying pd.DataFrame objects don't recognize numerical inputs as 'int' dtypes?

Comment: A series (or column in a df) of ints is different than an actual int. If you are down to the actual int like `5`, it no longer has the methods from pandas

Comment: Try `print(x, type(x))` and see if you get a primative like `int` or `string`. If so, a primative doesn't have access to the methods of its container. You are probably acting on items when you want to act on columns.

Answer (score 0):

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html

As mentioned in the comment just do

```
x.replace(None, 'N/A', True)
```

Comment: I'm not sure what that link has to do with your answer. Also, if posting an answer from the comments, generally, you'd want to make it a community wiki.

Comment: @Zev Yea my bad, not a good post, I would've commented but I can't yet cuz I don't have enough points. I think your answer above is right though.